# How do I clone element events excluding data in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

I am trying to clone the html div element with class ".age-sex-details" and the events bound to the ".age-sex-remove" and ".age-sex-add" classes shown below using the jquery [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function. I am able to clone the div, the events mentioned above and data entered into the input boxes using the .clone(true) function, but I need to clone the div element and the mentioned events but not the data entered in the "count" and "age" input fields. Is this possible?

### Brief Description of Code

The jQuery code below consists of two functions in the document ready function. You can ignore the first one. The second function is where I do the cloning. I clone the div element shown in the HTML below and insert it after itself.

### iQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".age-sex-remove").click(function() {
            var index = $(".age-sex-details").length;
            if ( index > 1) {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                $($(".age-sex-add")[index - 2]).show();
            } else {
                console.log("only one set of age sex details, therefore clear values.")
            }
        });

        /**
         * Clone age-sex-details div including events and excluding data.
         * Hide the previous add new sex age details link.
         */
        $(".age-sex-add").click(function() {
            var index = $(".age-sex-details").length;
            console.log("Index = " +index);
            $($(".age-sex-details")[index - 1]).clone(true).insertAfter($(".age-sex-details")[index - 1]);
            $($(".age-sex-add")[index - 1]).hide();
        });
    });
```

### HTML

```
<div class="form-inline age-sex-details">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Count">Count</label>
        <input type="text" name="count" class="form-control" id="Count" />
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" id="Age" />
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Sex">Sex</label>
        <select name="sex" class="form-control" id="Sex">
            <option value="0">Female</option>
            <option value="1">Male</option>
        </select>
    </div>    
    <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove age-sex-remove">&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus age-sex-add">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle for the code](http://jsfiddle.net/ysfiqbl/AqKEQ/)

Thanks,
Yusuf

Comment: How about $(".age-sex.details > *").text(""); after clone?

Comment: What exactly do you want to have removed? Do you mean the value put into the inputs?

Comment: @Colin, `clone()` does not clone dynamic state (such as values entered in `<input>` elements).

Comment: @AngularAddict Thanks for the suggestion. I need to remove the text from the elements within a particular div with class _age-sex-details_. Your suggestions leaves me with an empty set of divs for all divs that have the class _.age-sex-details_.

Comment: @Colin DeClue I want to remove the values that will be in the inputs of the cloned elements. I basically want to clear the values in the input boxes of the cloned div and was wondering if there was a better way of clearing the values instead of looping through the div and clearing the input values individually.

Comment: @ysfiqbl, `clone()` is explicitly documented ([first paragraph, after the headers](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)) as not copying `<input>` values. Unless you have set `value` HTML attributes you want to clear in the clones?

Comment: You could first get cloned html ro variable. Then do as i said with variable as selector. And then append to html variable contents.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I noticed that too, but it does copy the dynamic values. I even tried setting the default values in the input boxes using `value=""`.

Comment: @ysfiqbl, you're right, I can repro this on Firefox. Looks like the docs are wrong, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call [removeData()](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) without arguments after cloning the element:

```
var cloneWithEventsOnly = $("selector").clone(true).removeData();
```

**EDIT:** It looks like you want to clear the form control values (which should not be copied in the first place according to `clone()`'s [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), but apparently are).

In that case, you can match form controls with the [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector and clear their values with [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var cloneWithoutValues = $("selector").clone(true).find(":input").val("").end();
```

Or, in your particular case:

```
var source = $(".age-sex-details").eq(index - 1);
source.clone(true).find(":input").val("").end().insertAfter(source);
```

Comment: I don't see him calling `.data()` anywhere, so I don't think that's what he means.

Comment: I tried calling `.removeData()`, but it does not do anything. Probably because I do not set the values using `.data()`.
According to jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.removedata/) I can use `.removeData()` to remove data that was set by `.data()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var data = $($(".age-sex-details")[index - 1]).clone(true);
 $(data).find(':input').val("");;
 $(datal).insertAfter($(".age-sex-details")[index - 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works if you replace 
 `$(html).insertAfter($(".age-sex-details")[index - 1]);`
with
` $(data).insertAfter($(".age-sex-details")[index - 1]);`